# How to configure Ethereum on Bifrost

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I am building a blockchain application that allows investors purchase ICOs using ETH on the Stellar network. I use Bifrost to connect my application to stellar network. But when I startEthereum on Bifrost, I receive a **network failed error**. 
 
Here's my code:

```
var params = {
            network: 'test',
            horizonURL: 'https://13.65.197.217:11626',
            bifrostURL: 'http://13.65.197.217:8000',
            assetCode: 'TOKE',
            price: '1',
            issuingPublicKey:'JIYUTBYTFHIUCHYCFTY6758398NUYRPWZ4WL4KZUXDMHLVZWPOQ', 
            preSaleMode: false,

            };

    var session = new Bifrost.Session(params);

        session.startEthereum(onEvent).then(params => {
            setStatus("Waiting for a transaction...", 10);

            document.getElementsById("address").innerText = params.address;

            keypair = params.keypair;
        })
            .catch(err => {
                setStatus("Error", 0);
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
```

after the line `session.startEthereum`, the code throws a **Network Error**.

Here's the configuration on the linux server:

```
[ethereum] master_public_key = "tpubD6HjUbkrYhZ4YiWwEHKPdFUTcPXZ3f3QXuqbdPVmgwUHvp7tkEmM44toHjXGLrWWdSDaDWM5KgiMkCQu7jJRamThZNztFOn8c5SHePyngGQ"
rpc_server = "https://geth.ethereum.org" 
network_id = "3" 
minimum_value_eth = "0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

AFter days of research, i discovered that i had to download and install geth on my server then run it as rpc using geth --rpc. this downloaded ethereum blockchain. in the configuration file on the bifrostserver, i changed the field rpc_server to the url of my geth and that was all.